# Cannot load in ggplot2 or seemingly anything

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I haven't used R since I finished my masters.

I deleted a bunch of files back then.

Anyway I tried to work on things again but ggplot2 was not loading. I've tried now deleting RStudio and reinstalling fully, deleting win-library completely. Nothing seems to work:

> install.packages("ggplot2")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘colorspace’, ‘utf8’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘munsell’, ‘R6’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘fansi’, ‘magrittr’, ‘pillar’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘vctrs’, ‘digest’, ‘glue’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘withr’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
cli           2.0.2  3.4.1              TRUE
colorspace    1.4-1  2.0-3              TRUE
utf8          1.1.4  1.2.2              TRUE
farver        2.0.3  2.1.1              TRUE
labeling        0.3  0.4.2             FALSE
lifecycle     0.2.0  1.0.3             FALSE
R6            2.4.1  2.5.1             FALSE
RColorBrewer  1.1-2  1.1-3             FALSE
viridisLite   0.3.0  0.4.1             FALSE
fansi         0.4.1  1.0.3              TRUE
magrittr        1.5  2.0.3              TRUE
pillar        1.4.3  1.8.1             FALSE
vctrs         0.2.4  0.4.2              TRUE
digest       0.6.25 0.6.29              TRUE
glue          1.4.0  1.6.2              TRUE
gtable        0.3.0  0.3.1             FALSE
isoband       0.2.1  0.2.6              TRUE
rlang         0.4.5  1.0.6              TRUE
scales        1.1.0  1.2.1             FALSE
tibble        3.0.1  3.1.8              TRUE
withr         2.2.0  2.5.0             FALSE
ggplot2       3.3.0  3.3.6             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/cli_2.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 397120 bytes (387 KB)
downloaded 387 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/colorspace_1.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2549008 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/utf8_1.1.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 214574 bytes (209 KB)
downloaded 209 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/farver_2.0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1910691 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/munsell_0.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 244203 bytes (238 KB)
downloaded 238 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/fansi_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 222782 bytes (217 KB)
downloaded 217 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/magrittr_1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155738 bytes (152 KB)
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/pkgconfig_2.0.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 22161 bytes (21 KB)
downloaded 21 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vctrs_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1018801 bytes (994 KB)
downloaded 994 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/digest_0.6.25.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 248623 bytes (242 KB)
downloaded 242 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/glue_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 157284 bytes (153 KB)
downloaded 153 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/isoband_0.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3303519 bytes (3.2 MB)
downloaded 3.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tibble_3.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 407904 bytes (398 KB)
downloaded 398 KB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘colorspace’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘farver’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘munsell’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘fansi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘pkgconfig’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘isoband’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpURKnmJ\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘labeling’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘R6’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘pillar’, ‘gtable’, ‘scales’, ‘withr’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/labeling_0.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 10156 bytes
downloaded 10156 bytes

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/R6_2.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 63422 bytes (61 KB)
downloaded 61 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RColorBrewer_1.1-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11638 bytes (11 KB)
downloaded 11 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/viridisLite_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1267090 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.8.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 479977 bytes (468 KB)
downloaded 468 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtable_0.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 92733 bytes (90 KB)
downloaded 90 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 270609 bytes (264 KB)
downloaded 264 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/withr_2.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 102089 bytes (99 KB)
downloaded 99 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3061989 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

- installing *source* package 'labeling' ...
  ** package 'labeling' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'labeling'
  finding HTML links ... done
  extended                                html
  extended.figures                        html
  gnuplot                                 html
  heckbert                                html
  labeling-internal                       html
  labeling-package                        html
  matplotlib                              html
  nelder                                  html
  rpretty                                 html
  sparks                                  html
  thayer                                  html
  wilkinson                               html
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (labeling)
  In R CMD INSTALL
- installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
  ** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
- removing 'C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
  In R CMD INSTALL
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'R6' ...
  ** package 'R6' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'R6'
  finding HTML links ... done
  R6Class                                 html
  as.list.R6                              html
  is.R6                                   html
  *** copying figures
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (R6)
  In R CMD INSTALL
- installing *source* package 'RColorBrewer' ...
  ** package 'RColorBrewer' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'RColorBrewer'
  finding HTML links ... done
  ColorBrewer                             html
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (RColorBrewer)
  In R CMD INSTALL
- installing *source* package 'viridisLite' ...
  ** package 'viridisLite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'viridisLite'
  finding HTML links ... done
  viridis                                 html
  viridis.map                             html
  *** copying figures
  ** building package indices
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (viridisLite)
  In R CMD INSTALL
- installing *source* package 'gtable' ...
  ** package 'gtable' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'gtable'
  finding HTML links ... done
  bind                                    html
  gtable-package                          html
  gtable                                  html
  gtable_add_cols                         html
  gtable_add_grob                         html
  gtable_add_padding                      html
  gtable_add_rows                         html
  gtable_add_space                        html
  gtable_col                              html
  gtable_filter                           html
  Rd warning: C:/Users/Ahsan/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSqbjMI/R.INSTALL7ee849be739a/gtable/man/gtable_filter.Rd:12: file link 'regular expression' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
  Rd warning: C:/Users/Ahsan/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSqbjMI/R.INSTALL7ee849be739a/gtable/man/gtable_filter.Rd:15: file link 'as.character' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
  gtable_height                           html
  gtable_matrix                           html
  gtable_row                              html
  gtable_show_layout                      html
  gtable_spacer                           html
  gtable_trim                             html
  gtable_width                            html
  is.gtable                               html
  print.gtable                            html
  *** copying figures
  ** building package indices
  ** installing vignettes
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (gtable)
  In R CMD INSTALL
- installing *source* package 'withr' ...
  ** package 'withr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  ** help
  *** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'withr'
  finding HTML links ... done
  defer                                   html
  devices                                 html
  Rd warning: C:/Users/Ahsan/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpi2NkSE/R.INSTALL75e85eba3949/withr/man/devices.Rd:228: file link 'X11' in package 'grDevices' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
  makevars_user                           html
  set_makevars                            html
  with_                                   html
  with_collate                            html
  with_connection                         html
  with_db_connection                      html
  with_dir                                html
  with_envvar                             html
  with_file                               html
  with_gctorture2                         html
  with_language                           html
  with_libpaths                           html
  with_locale                             html
  with_makevars                           html
  with_options                            html
  with_package                            html
  Rd warning: C:/Users/Ahsan/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpi2NkSE/R.INSTALL75e85eba3949/withr/man/with_package.Rd:68: file link '.libPaths' in package 'base' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
  with_par                                html
  with_path                               html
  with_rng_version                        html
  with_seed                               html
  with_sink                               html
  with_temp_libpaths                      html
  with_tempfile                           html
  with_timezone                           html
  withr                                   html
  *** copying figures
  ** building package indices
  ** installing vignettes
  ** testing if installed package can be loaded
  *** arch - i386
  *** arch - x64
- DONE (withr)
  In R CMD INSTALL
  ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'pillar'
- removing 'C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/pillar'
  In R CMD INSTALL
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
- removing 'C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/scales'
  In R CMD INSTALL
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency 'scales' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
- removing 'C:/Users/Ahsan/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
  In R CMD INSTALL
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpURKnmJ\downloaded_packages’

Comment: You need `rlang` >= v1.0.06 to load `lifecycle`, which in turn is needed for `scales` which is needed for `ggplot2`. Restart R, try to upgrade to more recent `rlang`, and try it again. Good luck.

Comment: When you receive the prompt to install the source, just response with no. The slight change in the most recent version is not worth the trouble of compiling the source code.